# How to get sorted result by createdAt in local data

Tags: parse-platform

I want to get result sorted by createdAt from local data, But createdAt is nil in local data. What should I do?

NG (createdAt is nil.)

```
object.pinInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) in
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo : object.createdAt!)
```

OK

```
object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) in
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo : object.createdAt!)
```

Comment: PLease add some more info/detail

Comment: NG (createdAt is nil.)
 object.pinInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) in
     var query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
       query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo : object.createdAt!)

OK
 object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) in
     var query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
       query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo : object.createdAt!)